# How to combine rows in R when data includes dates and time

Tags: r, date, merge

I have a series of spreadsheets with open and close times listed on separate lines per the document.

[image]

What I need is this:

```
1/4/2014 1:45:00PM   1/4/2014  11:00:00PM 1/4/2014   4:35:00PM 1/4/2014 11:00:00PM
1/11/2014 11:00:00PM 1/12/2014 2:05:00PM  1/11/2014 11:00:00PM 1/12/2014 12:43:00PM
```

I have solutions for merging numeric or character data by the techniques don't work for dates and times.1

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Could you provide more information, e.g. the code you are using ? The structure of the output you'd like (a vector as displayed ? or a dataframe?). Lots of alternatives for doing this... convert all your times/dates to numeric (`as.numeric()`).

Comment: looks like you may want tidy data. Perhaps look into the tidyverse's tidyr package.

Comment: Thanks, tidyr did most what I needed after getting clarification on what the data meant.